# FirebaseApp is auto start when i not init it?

Tags: android, firebase

```
03-02 21:03:03.087 6253-6253/ D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
03-02 21:03:03.093 6253-6253/ D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
03-02 21:03:03.099 6253-6253/ I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9256
03-02 21:03:03.099 6253-6253/ I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-02 21:03:03.120 6253-6253/ I/FA: Collection disabled with firebase_analytics_collection_enabled=0
03-02 21:03:03.129 6253-6253/ I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful


 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!--Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist-->
    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mi.android.globalpersonalassistant.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />
    <!--end-->
```

In my Application, not init it! why FirebaseApp is atuo-start! Can it disable it not start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase initializes automatically when integrated using the documented steps because it brings in a ContentProvider which is initialized automatically by Android when the app launches.  The JavaDoc for [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) talks a little bit about this.

[This blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html) goes into even more detail.